# JPA Composite Key WITH Sequence in spring boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

Is it possible in plain JPA or Hibernate a composite key, where an element of the composite key is a sequence and the other element is a mapped with a foreign key.

I have a composite key in my table and part of it needs to be generated by a sequence.
I tried the following, but it doesn't work

class produit

```
@Entity
public class Produit{
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProduitClientPK id=new ProduitClientPK();
    private Client client;

    public ProduitClientPK getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ProduitClientPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

  

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_CLIENT")
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }


}
```

class composite key :

```
@Embeddable
public class ProduitClientPK implements Serializable {
    private long fkproduit;
    private long clientSeq;

    @Column(name = "FK_PRODUIT")
    @Id
    public long getFkProduit() {
        return fkproduit;
    }

    public void setFkProduit(long fkproduit) {
        this.fkproduit= fkproduit;
    }

    @Column(name = "CLIENT_SEQ")
    @Id
    public long getclientSeq() {
        return clientSeq;
    }

    public void setClientSeq(long clientSeq) {
        this.clientSeq= clientSeq;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        PolPolAvnEntityPK that = (PolPolAvnEntityPK) o;
        return fkPolice == that.fkPolice &&
                avnSeq == that.avnSeq;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(fkPolice, avnSeq);
    }
}
```

class client :

```
@Entity

public class Client {
    private Long id;
    private Set<Produit> produits;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PRODUIT")

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<Produit> getProduits() {
        return produits;
    }

    public void setProduits(Set<Produit> avenants) {
        this.produits = produits;
    }


    public void addProduits(Produit  produit){
        produit.setClient(this);
        produits.add(produit);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add `@Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  private Long id;` in your  `ProduitClientPK`

Comment: It's done ,But it still doesn't work

Comment: I don't see that in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model does not make much sense, unless I misunderstood it. Why do you need `FK_PRODUIT` to be part of the primary key? If you are using a sequence for `CLIENT_SEQ`, this is enough to make the row unique. Apart from that, shouldn't this `CLIENT_SEQ` value be generated when persisting a `Client`? IMO you should be using something like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Produit{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private Client client;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_CLIENT")
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've met with the same issue not so long time ago. It would be better not to use @EmbeddedId in your case if you want one of PK fields to be generated by your database. I'm not expert in Hibernate, but as I know Hibernate doesn't try to set values to ID fields only if they are annotated by @GeneratedValue. Only this annotation can tell Hibernate to rely on database sequences. And you cannot do it in Embeddable class.

Try just use one @Id field if you want one to be generated.